# Clustering data on 2 servers with single indexing occupies double space?

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I am having 2 servers, with a single cluster holding them. In the present case, indexing is done on both the servers, and the queries work fine. The question is-- If we index the data on server 1 and leave it as it is (non indexed) on server 2, with the same cluster binding them still, will the indexed data also occupy space on server 1 (non-indexed) ? i.e. Will there be a duplication of storage or not?

Comment: What do you mean by indexing data on server1 but leave it as it is on server 2? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I mean when i index data in one node then is it take memory on both nodes? @javanna